# Doctrine DBAL updating all rows

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to update posts table by id. But when I tried that doctrine updates all rows in posts table not just selected id.

> Note that queryBuilder coming from DriverManager not from EntityManager

```
public function store(RequestInterface $request)
{
    $db = new Config();
    $db->queryBuilder()
        ->update("posts")
        ->set("title", "?")
        ->set("content", "?")
        ->where("id", "?")
        ->setParameter(0, $request->get("title"))
        ->setParameter(1, $request->get("content"))
        ->setParameter(2, $request->get("id"));

    return redirect()->route("posts.index");
}
```

config class

```
class Config
{
private $info;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->info = [
        'dbname' => 'cms',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => '123456',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    ];
}

public function conn()
{
    return DriverManager::getConnection($this->info, $this->config());
}

private function config()
{
    return new Configuration();
}

public function queryBuilder()
{
    return $this->conn()->createQueryBuilder();
}
```

is there anything wrong about the above codes ? if is, how can I fix it ?

Comment: It is always challenging to help when the posted code does not match your actual code.  There is no $qb->queryBuider() method unless you have modified the DBAL connection object.  Nor are you executing the query.  You could try examining the generated sql but I suspect you have something completely different going on.

Comment: @Cerad I edited my question. it's comng from config class

Comment: Still not seeing any evidence that you are actually executing the query.

Comment: I found. ->where("id", "?") should be ->where("id = ?")